# Updating JPanel with Label Texts

Tags: java, swing

I am working on an app which will get info from the user through the buttons and text frames in the MyPanel class. I want to display the courses-infos the user entered in the DisplayTable panel. I want it to update each time the add course button in the MyPanel class is pressed. I tried calling the setLabelText method from the MyPanel class, and what the actual function is supposed to do is update the panel and display the text for each element in the passed lists when the button is clicked, But still could not update. Could you tell me  how can I update the DisplayPanel's infoLabel text each time the addCourseButton is pressed?

[image]

Class Main

```
public class Main {
    //TODO
    // PREVENT TYPE MISMATCH IN TEXT FIELDS
    // DISPLAY A TABLE OF COURSE NAMES - COURSE CREDITS - COURSE NAME AND THE GPA
    // CLEAN UP
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Class MyFrame

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{

    MainPanel mainPanel;

    MyFrame(){
        mainPanel = new MainPanel();

        this.add(mainPanel);
        this.setTitle("GPA Calculator");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        this.setVisible(true);
    } 
}
```

Class MainPanel

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    DisplayPanel displayPanel = new DisplayPanel();
    MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel(displayPanel);

    MainPanel() {
        this.add(myPanel);
        this.add(displayPanel);
    }
}
```

Class MyPanel

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    ArrayList<String> courseNames;
    ArrayList<Integer> courseCredits;
    ArrayList<Double> courseGrades;
    Thread thread;
    JLabel nameLabel;
    JLabel creditLabel;
    JLabel gradeLabel;
    JTextField nameField;
    JTextField creditField;
    JTextField gradeField;
    JButton calculateButton;
    JButton addCourseButton;
    JButton resetButton;
    JLabel message;

    DisplayPanel displayPanel;

    double result = 0;
    int tempInt = 0;
    double tempDouble = 0;

    MyPanel(DisplayPanel displayPanel) {

        this.displayPanel = new DisplayPanel();

        message = new JLabel();
        message.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        message.setFont(new Font("Helvetica Neue", Font.PLAIN, 35));
        message.setForeground(new Color(0xA1683A));
        message.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        courseNames = new ArrayList();
        courseCredits = new ArrayList();
        courseGrades = new ArrayList();

        nameLabel = new JLabel();
        nameLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        nameLabel.setText("Course Name");
        nameLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica Neue", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        nameLabel.setForeground(new Color(0xA1683A));
        nameLabel.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        nameField = new JTextField();
        nameField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,30));
        nameField.setMaximumSize(nameField.getPreferredSize());

        creditLabel = new JLabel();
        creditLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        creditLabel.setText("Course Credits(ECTS)");
        creditLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica Neue", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        creditLabel.setForeground(new Color(0xA1683A));
        creditLabel.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        creditField = new JTextField();
        creditField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,30));
        creditField.setMaximumSize(creditField.getPreferredSize());

        gradeLabel = new JLabel();
        gradeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        gradeLabel.setText("Your Grade");
        gradeLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica Neue", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        gradeLabel.setForeground(new Color(0xA1683A));
        gradeLabel.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        gradeField = new JTextField();
        gradeField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,30));
        gradeField.setMaximumSize(gradeField.getPreferredSize());


        resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
        resetButton.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        resetButton.addActionListener(this);
        addCourseButton = new JButton("Add Course");
        addCourseButton.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        addCourseButton.addActionListener(this);
        calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate GPA");
        calculateButton.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        calculateButton.addActionListener(this);

        //spacing and adding the elements
        this.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,20)));
        this.add(nameLabel);
        this.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
        this.add(nameField);
        this.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,20)));
        this.add(creditLabel);
        this.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
        this.add(creditField);
        this.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,20)));
        this.add(gradeLabel);
        this.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
        this.add(gradeField);
        this.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,20)));
        this.add(addCourseButton);
        this.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,5)));
        this.add(calculateButton);
        this.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,5)));
        this.add(resetButton);
        this.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
        this.add(message);

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        this.setBackground(new Color(0xEED2CC));
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    }

    //calculate the GPA
    public double calculateGPA(){
        for (Integer courseCredit : courseCredits) {
            tempInt += courseCredit;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<courseGrades.size();i++){
            tempDouble += courseGrades.get(i) * courseCredits.get(i);
        }
        return tempDouble/tempInt;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throws NumberFormatException {

        if(e.getSource().equals(addCourseButton)){

            //add items from the textFields to lists
            String tempText = nameField.getText();
            int tempCredit = Integer.parseInt(creditField.getText());
            double tempGrade = Double.parseDouble(gradeField.getText());
            courseNames.add(tempText);
            courseCredits.add(tempCredit);
            courseGrades.add(tempGrade);

            //set textFields to empty
            nameField.setText("");
            creditField.setText("");
            gradeField.setText("");

            //display a message for 3 seconds
            thread = new Thread();
            thread.start();
            message.setText("Course Added Successfully!");
            Timer timer = new Timer(3000, a -> message.setText(null));
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();

            //add to table panel
            displayPanel.setLabelText(courseNames,courseCredits,courseGrades);
            //displayPanel.update();  
        }

        //calculate the GPA, initialize the display panel
        //to display the courses names-credits-results and the gpa
        //as a table
        if(e.getSource().equals(calculateButton)){
            result = calculateGPA();
            message.setText(result + "");
        }

        //clear the lists,text fields and the message
        //get rid of the table panel
        if(e.getSource().equals(resetButton)){
            courseNames.clear();
            courseGrades.clear();
            courseCredits.clear();
            tempDouble = 0;
            tempInt = 0;
            displayPanel.removeAll();
            displayPanel.repaint();
            nameField.setText("");
            creditField.setText("");
            gradeField.setText("");
            message.setText(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Class DisplayPanel

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DisplayPanel extends JPanel {

    JLabel infoLabel;

    public DisplayPanel() {

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        this.setBackground(new Color(0xEED2CC));
        this.setLayout(null);

        infoLabel = new JLabel();
        infoLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        infoLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica Neue", Font.PLAIN, 35));
        infoLabel.setForeground(new Color(0xA1683A));
        infoLabel.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        infoLabel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        infoLabel.setOpaque(true);


        this.add(infoLabel);
    }
 
    public void setLabelText(ArrayList<String> courseNames, ArrayList<Integer> courseCredits, ArrayList<Double> courseGrades) {

        this.removeAll();
        this.add(infoLabel);
        this.repaint();
        this.revalidate();

        for (String name : courseNames) {
            infoLabel.setText(name + "\t" + courseCredits.get(courseNames.indexOf(name)) + "\t" + courseGrades.get(courseNames.indexOf(name)));
        }

        infoLabel.setOpaque(true);  
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Could anyone take a look?"* Yep, done. Can you post a [mre] and a more specific question?

Comment: @Abra Exactly that, addCourse does not update the DisplayPanel to show the infoLabel text. Not as a table tho, I want to have it displayed as JLabel’s text’s with each course in a line.

Comment: Better to use a JTable, or if you want tabular lines of text, a JList. And next, get rid of the parallel ArrayLists as that can lead to hard to debug errors.

Comment: `setLayout(null);` -- not good, not at all

Comment: Thank you, I will try JList. But the main problem still is how to update the display panel each time the button is pressed after adding JList to DisplayPanel

Comment: A basic bug: you never add the acted on DisplayPanel to the GUI! Not the one that you're adding the JLabel to. You're creating two of these guys. Create one and only ***one*** of these components, add it to the GUI and change the state of that one and same component.

Comment: How to discover this: look at your code above, and see how many times you call `new DisplayPanel()`. This should only be called ***once***, you call it ***twice***, one you add to the GUI, the other you try to add JLabels onto.

Comment: Also, re-setting the text in the displayLabel will delete the prior text added. This is why you should use a JList, or better a JTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will concentrate on fixing your immediate problem, i.e. displaying text in the `infoLabel` in class `DisplayPanel`.

You have three problems. The first is in the constructor of class `MyPanel`.

```java
MyPanel(DisplayPanel displayPanel) {
    this.displayPanel = new DisplayPanel();
```

You are ignoring the constructor parameter and creating a new instance of `DisplayPanel`. Hence member `displayPanel` of class `MyPanel` is not the same object that you created in class `MainPanel`. So you are calling methods on a `DisplayPanel` that was **not** added to `MainPanel`. You need to change that line to the following.

```java
MyPanel(DisplayPanel displayPanel) {
    this.displayPanel = displayPanel;
```

The second problem is that you set a null layout in `DisplayPanel`. When there is no [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) you need to explicitly set the bounds of any components you add to the `JPanel`. You aren't doing that and hence your `JLabel` is not displayed. Simply remove this line from the constructor of `DisplayPanel`

```java
this.setLayout(null);
```

Finally, in method `setLabelText`, of class `DisplayPanel`, you only need to change the `JLabel` text, via method `setText`. No need to remove all the components and add them again. The method should be as follows.

```
public void setLabelText(ArrayList<String> courseNames, ArrayList<Integer> courseCredits, ArrayList<Double> courseGrades) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String name : courseNames) {
        sb.append(name + "\t" + courseCredits.get(courseNames.indexOf(name)) + "\t" + courseGrades.get(courseNames.indexOf(name)));
    }
    infoLabel.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

### Edit

If I were tasked with making this application, I would do it something like the following.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class GpaCalcs implements Runnable {
    private DefaultTableModel  tableModel;
    private JFormattedTextField  courseCreditsTextField;
    private JFormattedTextField  gradeTextField;
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JTable  table;
    private JTextField  courseNameTextField;

    public void run() {
        try {
            createAndDisplayGui();
        }
        catch (Exception x) {
            throw new RuntimeException(x);
        }
    }

    private void addCourse(ActionEvent event) {
        Object[] row = new Object[3];
        row[0] = courseNameTextField.getText();
        row[1] = courseCreditsTextField.getValue();
        row[2] = gradeTextField.getValue();
        tableModel.addRow(row);
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() throws ParseException {
        frame = new JFrame("GPA Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createButtonsPanel(JPanel formPanel, GridBagConstraints gbc) {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton addCourseButton = new JButton("Add Course");
        addCourseButton.addActionListener(this::addCourse);
        buttonsPanel.add(addCourseButton);
        JButton calcGpaButton = new JButton("Calculate GPA");
        buttonsPanel.add(calcGpaButton);
        JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(this::reset);
        buttonsPanel.add(resetButton);
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        formPanel.add(buttonsPanel, gbc);
    }

    private JScrollPane createDisplayPanel() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"Course", "Credits", "Grade"};
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);
        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private JPanel createFormPanel() throws ParseException {
        JPanel formPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 5;
        gbc.insets.left = 5;
        gbc.insets.right = 5;
        gbc.insets.top = 5;
        JLabel courseNameLabel = new JLabel("Course Name");
        formPanel.add(courseNameLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        courseNameTextField = new JTextField(10);
        formPanel.add(courseNameTextField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        JLabel courseCreditLabel = new JLabel("Course Credits (ECTS)");
        formPanel.add(courseCreditLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("####"); // throws java.text.ParseException
        courseCreditsTextField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        courseCreditsTextField.setColumns(10);
        formPanel.add(courseCreditsTextField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        JLabel gradeLabel = new JLabel("Your Grade");
        formPanel.add(gradeLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        formatter = new MaskFormatter("#.##");
        gradeTextField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        gradeTextField.setColumns(10);
        formPanel.add(gradeTextField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        createButtonsPanel(formPanel, gbc);
        return formPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() throws ParseException {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        mainPanel.add(createFormPanel());
        mainPanel.add(createDisplayPanel());
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private void reset(ActionEvent event) {
        courseNameTextField.setText("");
        courseCreditsTextField.setText("");
        gradeTextField.setText("");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new GpaCalcs());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're creating two DisplayPanels, adding one to the GUI and trying to change the state of the other non-displayed DisplayPanel.

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    DisplayPanel displayPanel = new DisplayPanel(); // *** HERE ***
    MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel(displayPanel); 

    MainPanel() {
        this.add(myPanel);
        this.add(displayPanel);
    }
}
```

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    // ....

    DisplayPanel displayPanel;

    // ...

    MyPanel(DisplayPanel displayPanel) {

        this.displayPanel = new DisplayPanel();   // *** and HERE ***

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

And in fact, in the MainPanel, you are trying to add your DisplayPanel object to two different containers, which is not legal in Swing, and only the second add method will count.

Suggestions:

- ***First and foremost***: create a class to hold the key information that you're displaying. In my example below, I show how to do this, how to create a CourseInfo class to hold each "row" of data that you will eventually display. In fact, no matter how you decide to display the data, I think that doing this first is the most important thing that you can and should do.
- Create one and only one component, add it and change its state when needed.
- Use a JList or better a JTable to display the data.
- Avoid null layouts and setBounds and instead use the layout managers. Check out the layout manager tutorial here: Layout manager tutorial here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- Avoid parallel arrays or ArrayLists. Instead create a class to hold a row of data, and a single ArrayList of this type that you fill-up.
- Focus first on getting your GUI working, and secondarily making it pretty and such. In other words, make sure things work and display before worrying about fonts, colors, and such.

---

So, this is an example that uses a JTable and a custom table model and that displays like so:

[image]

First and foremost, a class to hold the key information that is being stored in each row of the JTable, called CourseInfo, and that has name String, credits int and grades double fields:

```
public class CourseInfo {
    private String name;
    private int credits;
    private double grades;

    public CourseInfo(String name, int credits, double grades) {
        this.name = name;
        this.credits = credits;
        this.grades = grades;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCredits() {
        return credits;
    }

    public double getGrades() {
        return grades;
    }

}
```

Next a TableModel class that holds a collection of the above information and allows the display of it in a JTable. I extend DefaultTableModel since this comes pre-wired with internal listeners that notify external objects (the JTable itself and any listeners added to it) when changes occur.

The constructor calls the super's constructor that accepts the COLUMNS String array, the one that holds the names of the columns displayed in the JTable's header. The internal (super's) model holds a collection of CourseInfo objects, and the tricky part is displaying one CourseInfo object in 3 columns. This is done by making the column count 3, and by overriding `getValueAt(...)` so that it returns the correct CourseInfo field depending on the column parameter

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CourseTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = { "Name", "Credits", "Grades" };

    public CourseTableModel() {
        super(COLUMNS, 0);
    }

    public void addCourseInfo(CourseInfo courseInfo) {
        super.addRow(new CourseInfo[] { courseInfo });
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMNS.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        CourseInfo courseInfo = (CourseInfo) super.getValueAt(row, 0);
        switch (column) {
        case 0:
            return courseInfo.getName();
        case 1:
            return courseInfo.getCredits();
        case 2:
            return courseInfo.getGrades();

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value: " + column);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (getRowCount() > 0) {
            return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
        } else {
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, the JPanel that displays the JTable, TablePanel. It also displays the GPA in a field. Note that there is not much to this class, that most of the program's logic is extracted out of it so that it focuses on the view or GUI aspect. The TableModel is passed into this via its constructor. It allows outside classes to set what is displayed in the gpaField via the `setGpa(...)` method:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TablePanel extends JPanel {
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTextField gpaField = new JTextField(10);
    
    public TablePanel(CourseTableModel tableModel) {
        int gap = 20;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));
        setBackground(CoursesMainPanel.BACKGROUND);
                
        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        
        table.setOpaque(false);
        scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        
        JPanel gpaPanel = new JPanel();
        gpaPanel.setOpaque(false);
        gpaPanel.add(new JLabel("GPA:"));
        gpaPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        gpaPanel.add(gpaField);
        
        gpaField.setEditable(false);
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
        add(gpaPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }
    
    public void setGpa(String gpaText) {
        gpaField.setText(gpaText);
    }
}
```

Next, the GetInfoPanel, a JPanel that gets the user's input. It has 3 JTextField's, JLabels, JButtons, and is organized via a GridBagLayout. It has a calcGpaButton, which is a relic from an earlier incarnation of this program, but which was disabled (and should be deleted probably), once I put the GPA calculation into a TableModelListener.

It too doesn't have much program logic, and outsources that to a control class, CoursesControl, that holds the code called by the button's ActionListeners. It has public methods, such as `public String getCourseName() {...` that allow the control class to extract information from this object when needed.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GetInfoPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Font LABEL_FONT = new Font("Helvetica Neue", Font.PLAIN, 35);
    private static final int TXT_FLD_COLS = 15;
    private JTextField courseNameField = new JTextField(TXT_FLD_COLS);
    private JTextField courseCreditsField = new JTextField(TXT_FLD_COLS);
    private JTextField courseGradesField = new JTextField(TXT_FLD_COLS);
    private JButton addCourseButton = new JButton("Add Course");
    private JButton calcGpaButton = new JButton("Calculate GPA"); // TODO: delete
    private JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    private JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    private int row = 0;
    private int insetGap = 2;
    private CoursesControl control;

    public GetInfoPanel() {
        int gap = 20;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setBackground(CoursesMainPanel.BACKGROUND);

        addToPanel("Course Name", courseNameField);
        addToPanel("Course Credits", courseCreditsField);
        addToPanel("Your Grade", courseGradesField);

        addCourseButton.addActionListener(e -> addCourse());
        calcGpaButton.addActionListener(e -> calcGpa());
        resetButton.addActionListener(e -> reset());
        exitButton.addActionListener(e -> exit());
        addCourseButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        calcGpaButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        resetButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        exitButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_X);
        
        calcGpaButton.setEnabled(false);  // Not needed

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 0));
        buttonPanel.setOpaque(false);
        buttonPanel.add(addCourseButton);
        buttonPanel.add(calcGpaButton);
        buttonPanel.add(resetButton);
        buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(6 * insetGap, 3 * insetGap, 3 * insetGap, 3 * insetGap);
        add(buttonPanel, gbc);
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseNameField.getText();
    }

    public String getCourseCredits() {
        return courseCreditsField.getText();
    }

    public String getCourseGrades() {
        return courseGradesField.getText();
    }

    public void clear() {
        courseNameField.setText("");
        courseCreditsField.setText("");
        courseGradesField.setText("");
        courseNameField.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public void setControl(CoursesControl control) {
        this.control = control;
    }

    private void addCourse() {
        if (control != null) {
            control.addCourse();
        }
        clear();
    }

    // TODO: delete as it is not really needed
    private void calcGpa() {
        if (control != null) {
            control.calcGpa();
        }
    }

    private void reset() {
        if (control != null) {
            control.reset();
        }
        clear();
    }

    private void exit() {
        if (control != null) {
            control.exit();
        }
    }

    private void addToPanel(String title, JTextField textField) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        row++;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(3 * insetGap, 3 * insetGap, 0, 3 * insetGap);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(title);
        label.setFont(LABEL_FONT);
        label.setForeground(CoursesMainPanel.LABEL_FOREGROUND);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(label, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = row;
        row++;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 3 * insetGap;
        textField.setFont(textField.getFont().deriveFont(20f));
        add(textField, gbc);
    }
}
```

Next the CoursesControl class, the one that holds most of the program's logic. This holds references to the view's GUI classes and methods that are called by the view's listeners. The `addCourse()` method extracts the text from the GetInfoPanel, it then validates that the numeric text is indeed numeric, and shows an error if not. If the data is good, it creates a new CourseInfo object with the data, and then adds a row to the table model by calling `tableModel.addCourseInfo(courseInfo);`. It adds a TableModelListener to the table model and whenever the model changes, this class calculates and displays the GPA by calling `tablePanel.setGpa` on the TablePanel instance:

```
import java.awt.Window;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;

public class CoursesControl {
    private GetInfoPanel getInfoPanel;
    private CourseTableModel tableModel;
    private TablePanel tablePanel;

    public void setGetInfoPanel(GetInfoPanel getInfoPanel) {
        this.getInfoPanel = getInfoPanel;
    }

    public void setTableModel(CourseTableModel tableModel) {
        this.tableModel = tableModel;
        tableModel.addTableModelListener(new TableListener());
    }
    
    public void setTablePanel(TablePanel tablePanel) {
        this.tablePanel = tablePanel;
    }

    public void addCourse() {
        if (getInfoPanel == null || tableModel == null) {
            return;
        }

        String courseName = getInfoPanel.getCourseName();
        String courseCreditsTxt = getInfoPanel.getCourseCredits();
        String courseGradesTxt = getInfoPanel.getCourseGrades();

        int courseCredits = 0;
        try {
            courseCredits = Integer.parseInt(courseCreditsTxt);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            String message = "Course credits should be an integer";
            String title = "Invalid Input";
            int type = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getInfoPanel, message, title, type);
            getInfoPanel.clear();
            return;
        }

        double courseGrades = 0.0;
        try {
            courseGrades = Double.parseDouble(courseGradesTxt);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            String message = "Course grades should be an number";
            String title = "Invalid Input";
            int type = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getInfoPanel, message, title, type);
            getInfoPanel.clear();
            return;
        }

        CourseInfo courseInfo = new CourseInfo(courseName, courseCredits, courseGrades);
        tableModel.addCourseInfo(courseInfo);
    }
    
    private class TableListener implements TableModelListener {

        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            if (tablePanel == null) {
                return;
            }
            int rows = tableModel.getRowCount();
            if (rows == 0) {
                tablePanel.setGpa("");
            } else {
                double sum = 0.0;
                int totalCredits = 0;
                for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                    int credits = (int) tableModel.getValueAt(row, 1);
                    double grade = (double) tableModel.getValueAt(row, 2);
                    
                    totalCredits += credits;
                    sum += credits * grade;
                }
                
                double gpa = sum / totalCredits;
                tablePanel.setGpa(String.format("%.2f", gpa));
            }
        }
        
    }

    public void reset() {
        if (tableModel != null) {
            tableModel.setRowCount(0);
        }
    }

    public void exit() {
        if (getInfoPanel != null) {
            Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(getInfoPanel);
            window.dispose();
        }
    }

    // TODO: delete as it isn't needed
    public void calcGpa() {
        // This is not really needed, since the GPA is calculated in a table model listener
        
    }

}
```

Finally, a main class to put it all together, to create a JFrame, and to display it all. This creates the main players in this production and hooks them together by passing the view objects to the control and passing the control to the view objects that need it:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CoursesMainPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final Color BACKGROUND = new Color(0xEED2CC);
    public static final Color LABEL_FOREGROUND = new Color(0xA1683A);

    private CoursesControl control = new CoursesControl();
    private GetInfoPanel getInfoPanel = new GetInfoPanel();
    private CourseTableModel tableModel = new CourseTableModel();
    private TablePanel tablePanel = new TablePanel(tableModel);

    public CoursesMainPanel() {
        getInfoPanel.setControl(control);
        control.setGetInfoPanel(getInfoPanel);
        control.setTableModel(tableModel);
        control.setTablePanel(tablePanel);

        int gap = 2;
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, gap, gap));
        add(getInfoPanel);
        add(tablePanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new CoursesMainPanel());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```